# Big Oh, Theta, and Omega of the following function w/ explanation?

Tags: big-o

Given

```
f(n) = 2 n^3 + 7 n^2 log(n^4)
```

What are the big Oh, Theta, and Omega statements which can be made?

I understand big Oh would be `O(n^3)` , but I am not sure what to look for, for the others. 
All I see is that is is bound by `n^3` , and cannot be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) article about big O notation.

Big O:

```
O(f(n)) = n^3, because  f(n) = 2n^3 + (7n^2)*log(n^4) =< 2n^3 + (7n^2)*n =< 9n^3,
for big enough n. As explained  below log(n^4) <= n, for big enough n.
```

Big Omega:

```
Omega(f(n)) = n^3; because f(n) = 2n^3 + (7n^2)*log(n^4) >= 2n^3 >= n^3,
for big enough n. 
You can assume that `(7n^2)*log(n^4) > 0` so 2n^3 + (7n^2)*log(n^4) > 2n^3 >= n^3.
```

Big Theta:

```
Theta(f(n)) = n^3; because it O(f(n)) = Omega(f(n)) = n^3,
```

In you example `n^3` dominates `7 n^2 log(n^4)`, "for big n".

More difficult will be to calculate O/Theta/Omega for function like: `g(n) = 7 n^2 log(n^4)`.

**=== UPDATE ===**

The main problem with `g(n)` function is to understand `log(n^4)` function (in my opinion it is a bit harder than simple `n`). log (n^4) = 4*log(n). 
So O(log(n^4)) = Omega(log(n^4)) = Theta(log(n^4)) = log(n),  because  log(n) <= log(n^4) < 4*log(n). This also means  log (n^4) <= n, for big enough n.

Finally this leads us to:

```
(7 n^2)*log(n^4) = (7n^2)*4log(n) = 28*(n^2)*(log n)
1*(n^2)*(log n)  <= 28*(n^2)*(log n) <= 29*(n^2)*(log n)
// O(g(n))= n^2 * log n  
// Omega(g(n))= n^2 * log n  
// Theta(g(n))= n^2 * log n
```

Comment: Ok and thank-you, I thought my hunch was correct.
Would you mind explaining the big Omega case in more detail please, and as to why the g(n) you gave would be more difficult?
Thank you